# Powershell Script execution from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Can someone help me here. I am trying to execute powershell script using C#. When i run with Visual Studio using IIS express its working but when i am deploying to local IIS its not able to execute Powershell script. Below is code what i have:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;
namespace PowerShellExecution
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clean the Result TextBox
            //ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;
            // Initialize PowerShell engine
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();
            // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            // shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);

         shell.Commands.AddScript("D:\\Test.ps1");
            // Execute the script
            var results = shell.Invoke();
            // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
            // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                // We use a string builder ton create our result text
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    // Add \r\n for line breaks
                    builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: permissions issue?...try to see if you could even read the d:\test.ps1 as a text file...that will tell you

Comment: Well permission wise it has full permission and as per debugger in VS its able to read the file.

Comment: debugger when running via iis express right...not iis...iis would run under a diff user

Comment: there is an option to deploy local to iis as well with default ID. Not sure what i am missing with as PS1 execution is nt working only.

Comment: default ID for IIS is a very low privileged account...this is done for security purposes...the user account running IIS will not have access to most of your machine...that's normal...you need to find out what the user account is...and then give it permissions for read/execute to your folder

Comment: Already completed these steps still PS is not getting executed

Answer (score 0):

Execution-policy have to be set to Unrestricted or you will have to sign your PowerShell-script. Then you could run execution-policy RemoteSigned

Comment: What happens if you run the ps script directly without invoking it through c#?

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Also if i run from Visual Studio using IIS express then also it works. Problem is when i host the package its not working. Any idea if i am calling PS in wrongly fashion in my code.

Comment: Try to run IIS/app pool as admin. If that works the issue is user rights as mentioned by some others.

Comment: Tried just now still its not picking up PS from code. I believe its still related to code execution :)